# Why content of page is not refreshed after changing data in MySQL directly?

Tags: mysql, django, caching, nginx, uwsgi

I've started a project using `Django`, `Nginx`, `uWSGI` and `MySQL` successfully.

Django gets data from MySQL and renders it to page, but when I change the data in MySQL, refreshing even for several times does not show changed data on the page.

The question came from studying Django cache.
I don't know how to test whether Django cache works or not?

```
    uwsgi:
    [uwsgi]
    vhost = false
    plugins = python
    socket = 127.0.0.1:8444
    master = true
    enable-threads = true
    workers = 1
    wsgi-file = project0/wsgi.py
    chdir = /home/www/project0
    touch-reload=/home/www/project0/reload
```

**views.py**

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from apps.blog.models import Timetest
    timetest=Timetest.objects.get(id=1)

    def index(req):
        content="welcome"
        return render(req,"blog/index.html",{"timetest":timetest})
```

**blog/index.html**

```
     {{ timetest }}
```

Answer (score 2):

move `timetest=Timetest.objects.get(id=1)` to your `index` function

```
def index(req):
    content = "welcome"
    timetest = Timetest.objects.get(id=1)
    return render(req, "blog/index.html", {"timetest": timetest})
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help ! @kia

Answer (score 1):

With WSGI, application code will be loaded on first request or when wsgi server starts, so all code placed outside of your view functions (or other functions that are executed outside views) will be executed once per server, and won't be executed again after page refresh. So your `timetest` variable will be populated once, and it's content will be kept between requests (it is actually populated with data on first use, but that doesn't matter here).

If you move line

```
timetest=Timetest.objects.get(id=1)
```

into view function, data will be fetched from database in each request, not just once.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help ! !!@GwynBleidD